# How to delete records easily when I try to optimize the data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

I am trying to delete some records to optimize the data.

If delete can replace select *, that's a good way to solve trouble.
for example.

```
select *
FROM  `wp_term_relationships`, wp_terms,wp_term_taxonomy  where  
'wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id`=wp_terms.term_id and wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
and   `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` 
BETWEEN 1154 
AND 11560;
```

I got many data.

I can't put delete to replace select *. I only delete data one  by one

I have to write down all of records and have to know which keys are related with "`object_id between 1154 and 11560`".

it is tough to see...

Comment: do you want to delete records from both the table in a single query...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will delete records from both the table (what select return)

```
DELETE 
FROM `wp_term_relationships`, `wp_terms` , `wp_term_taxonomy`
USING  `wp_term_relationships`, `wp_terms`, `wp_term_taxonomy`
WHERE
'wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id`=`wp_terms`.`term_id`
AND `wp_terms.term_id`=`wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id`
AND `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` BETWEEN 1154 AND 11560;
```

also try using JOIN clause